# Intellij run/debug target not finding classes within its own module

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea

The first screenshot shows a working run configuration.  The second shows a non working one.  They are identical module/classpath wise - at least according to the visible info.

Clearly there's a bug in IJ for this.  So .. how have others of you out there discovered a workaround for this? Also, ideas on what triggers this behavior?

WORKING run configuration
[image: WORKING run configuration]

NOT Working run configuration - gives ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

[image: NOT Working run configuration]

Here is the UDFPafDqm module - which DOES include hadoop jar  from Hortonworks  - so the ClassNotFoundException is ***bogus***

[image: Module libraries showing Hadoop jar is included]

Comment: Two different tests , they may have different runtime requirements. Does the second one has correct libraries in dependencies?  When test starts it prints a command line. You may check for its correctness.

Comment: Not following you here. The other test runs successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process above was repeatable : if you copy a run configuration it does not necessarily work - and can fail as described.  You have to start from scratch.  This is an IJ bug.